# "Mount" for .ISO's disappeared from context menu

Tags: windows-10, mount, context-menu, nero

I have Windows 10 and when right clicking on .ISO files there is usually "Mount" as an option.

But when I installed Nero Burning Room, "Mount" disappeared from the context menu.

How can I add it back?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This could be because Nero became the default program for opening `.iso` files, so you'll need to undo that.

Try right-clicking on any ISO file, and then in the `Open with...` option, select `Choose default program`. There you'll have to choose "Windows Explorer".

Check if the *Mount* option is back, and that's it!

Comment: An alternate option is to restore the default file association for .ISO files using CMD.EXE `assoc` utility (note: CMD builtin, not directly usable in Powershell). The default file type in the registry is `Windows.IsoFile`, so the command would be `assoc .iso=Windows.IsoFile`.

Comment: Yeah, that could also be a way, but I always prefer to use the "native" tools, instead of messing up with registry and that stuff, if possible (because it's easier, and there's less risk of messing up the system). Good point, though.

Comment: an alternate option is to uninstal this trash player VLC

Comment: Now any attempt to open ISO file lead to infinite explorer recursion...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate of adding `Mount` back to the context menu...

If you like having the default application for opening the `.iso` file to be something other than Explorer (i.e. Nero) then leave it as default.

When you want to "Mount" the .iso...
Right-click on any ISO file, then in the `Open with...` option, select `Windows Explorer`.

I like this option because the file still opens with my favorite burner app, but still allows me to mount it in Windows Explorer (which I use less often).

Answer (score 1):

If you've checked all of this stuff like me, and still don't get `Mount` in the context menu, go to this key in Regedit:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell\mount\command
```

If there is an entry there called `ProgrammaticAccessOnly`, delete it. That's what was preventing me from getting it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

right click on iso - open with - windows explorer = iso mounted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer does not answer the author's question.  They are already aware of the mount option, however, when they installed an application that option went away.  This answer should be modified to specifically address the author's question, "How can I add it back?", it is not helpful in it's current form.

Answer (score -2):

I got 2 options if anyone is still having problems.

1. With your ISO file left click and the ISO program should open, click "Continue to Try..." then the full program should open, after that you can highlight all files in there and drag to desktop or any file as you wish and continue to use the files on your desktop.
2. Goto drive "E:" or whatever you call yours and right click, hover over the UltraISO option and click "Mount", a folder should open and search for your ISO file you wish to import and click it. After that everything should go the same like the ISO did before.

(NOTE: These will not fix the "Mount" problems but they are only ways to use ISO differently yet almost the same way)